# How to use Git Tag number in place of SVN version Number in C# windows Service

Tags: c#, git, svn

I need some help in the SVN to Git Migration.

My project is Windows based project using Dev express 15.2 and the repository is in SVN. Code repository is successfully migrated to Git and able to launch and build the application using Visual Studio 2015.

There was one more windows service developed in C# which is using SVN's latest version number to build the application so that it can be distributed to users.

Now my main question is how can I build the application with this service by using Git Tag number instead of SVN version number?

Also in my .csproj file which is from the main project, I am using the below code for getting the latest version of SVN. So this needs to be replaced to get Git Tag Number

In my build service, there are three functions which are getting the details for the last build, the current SVN version, and the last SVN version.

1. Check SVN version
2. Check the last SVN version
3. CheckLastBuild()

These 3 function needs to be modified accordingly it suits to Git Tag number instead of Version number. Could you please provide your inputs/ feedback on how to proceed with this further so that it uses Git tag instead of the SVN version?

Comment: Git's tags are strings, not numbers; you can't just assume that they are version numbers unless you control them. Git commit hash IDs are random-looking, not sequential like SVN `-r` revision numbers. You'll need to do something to handle this, but what you'll need to do depends on what you want for results.

Comment: You might also want to comment on **why / what** you're trying to accomplish with this, because there might be a better way to do it in git than try to migrate your current version number handling to git, that does not have version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on how you create your git tags.
If you create tags with

```
git tag -a 1.2.3 -m “version 1.2.3”
```

you can use the git tags to get the Version Number.
But like **torek** mentioned, git tags are strings so you need to parse the git tag.

You can read the last tag with

```
git describe
```

You can use *–-abbrev=0* to only get the tag without commit hashes and you can use a regular expression to match only tags with a version schema:

```
git describe –abbrev=0 –-match="*[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*"
```

This would return *1.2.3* (if this was the last created tag)

You can find more info about creating *tags* [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) and *git describe* [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe).